# How do I proportionally reduce the size of my video?

Tags: quicktime, imovie

I want to resize the video pixels to a very small size so that I can use it to mosaic the original video through iMovie. Unfortunately, QuickTime player no longer supports custom arbitrary size. Is there a better suggestion?

Comment: Have you checked out Handbrake? This Q may end up being closed as it asks for software solutions...

Comment: @SolarMike No I don't. But I have took FFMPEG as a workaround. Thank you anyway!